# How can I calculate percentage of distribution that is below and above z scores only with SPSS without manually looking in z table

Tags: statistics, spss

I know how to calculate the corresponding z scores of all raw scores in my data using SPSS.

Now I want to calculate the percentage (probability format, like 0.989, 0.003 and etc is better) of distribution that is below and above correspond z score. I know how to do it manually with z table but I want to do it using only SPSS, without manual looking in z table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPSS has built-in cumulative distribution function (CDF) functions.  The one for the normal distribution takes the z-score, the distribution's mean, and the distribution's standard deviation as parameters.  So for a standard normal distribution:

```
COMPUTE probability = CDF.normal(z_score, 0, 1).
EXECUTE.
```

Most other distributions you might use are also available; the parameters used by the functions differ depending on how they're defined.  (For example, CDF.T takes the t-score and the number of degrees of freedom as parameters.)